# Bypass proxy if not available using python requests.Session()

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, proxy, python-requests

I am creating a software which access a internet URL. This software will be used on 2 PCs, one of them is behind the proxy.

To access the URL through proxy I have written below code :

```
proxies = {'https': 'https://my.proxy.server:1111'}
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies.update(proxies)
loginResponse = s.post(loginUrl, data=login_data, headers= headers)
```

This code works well on the computer which is behind the proxy but on other computer(which can access internet without proxy) I get an error : `Can't connect to proxy` . This is understandable.

My question is How can i modify this code so that it can work on both computers? What i want is to implement something like this:

```
proxy_server = XXXX
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies.update(proxy_server)

    if proxy_server not available : 
      s = requests.Session()

loginResponse = s.post(loginUrl, data=login_data, headers= headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to catch the proxy error like this:

```
proxy_server = XXXX
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies.update(proxy_server)

try:
    loginResponse = s.post(loginUrl, data=login_data, headers= headers)
except requests.exceptions.ProxyError as err:
    s = requests.Session()
    ...
```